# How to store token in react

Tags: reactjs, axios

I saved token in localStorage:

```
localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token)
```

and i want send token in every request, i added this to index.js

```
const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
if (token) {
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;
}
```

when start project, if token existed, axios send token in every request, but when i add token after start project, axiost don't send token, can i refresh default config after started project?

Comment: I would highly recommend you attach the header in a request interceptor. I've never had problems doing it like this.

Comment: You should run `axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;` at the point that the token is added as well if it did not exist when the page was loaded, though a request interceptor is probably a better solution

Comment: i use request interceptor and it works, thank you guy.

Answer (score 1):

this is my abstraction of Axios request, this allow auth token to be added or changed any time:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { API } from '../../constants';
import { store } from '../../../configureStore';

import { revokeAuthAction } from '../../../containers/Auth/actions';

export const getAuth = () => {
  const sessionString = localStorage.getItem('session');
  let auth;
  if (sessionString) {
    const session = JSON.parse(sessionString);
    auth = `${session.nation}|${session.user}|${session.token}`;
  }
  return auth;
};

/**
 * Create an Axios Client with defaults
 */
const client = axios.create({
  baseURL: API.BASEURL,
  headers: {
    Authorization: getAuth(),
    'Access-Control-Max-Age': 1728000,
  },
});

/**
 * Request Wrapper with default success/error actions
 */
const request = (options) => {
  const onSuccess = (response) => options.raw ? response : response.data;
    // console.debug('Request Successful!', response);
    // If options.raw is true, return all response

  const onError = (error) => {
    // console.error('Request Failed:', error.config);

    if (error.response) {
      if (error.response.status === 401) {
        // console.error('Unauthorized');
        store.dispatch(revokeAuthAction());
      } else {
        // Request was made but server responded with something
        // other than 2xx
        // console.error('Status:', error.response.status);
        // console.error('Data:', error.response.data);
        // console.error('Headers:', error.response.headers);
      }
    } else {
      // Something else happened while setting up the request
      // triggered the error
      // console.error('Error Message:', error.message);
    }

    return Promise.reject(error.response || error.message);
  };

  return client(options)
    .then(onSuccess)
    .catch(onError);
};

export default request;
```

Usage:

```
import request from '../../../../shared/lib/request';

[...]

const create = (content) => request(
  {
    url: API.MY_ENDPOINT,
    method: 'POST',
    data: content,
  });
```